# Creating new symbology to be used for ArcMap?

Tags: symbology, software-recommendations, vectorization, online, style-manager

I have a copy of scanned paper that has all the allotment may symbology that I am going to need them to add them to ArcMap 10.3.1. I have done creating new symbols that I worked on from my Ski Area project. This one is a bit different because you can create new symbols from within ArcMap's Style Manager. This paper has a symbology that was scanned and came from someone.

I have looked at this site http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0113/use-pngs-as-arcgis-picture-marker-symbols.html

I tried with the Paint at work but it does not a good job.

What is a good image to vector that I can go to that are online and it is free?

Comment: If you have ArcGIS Desktop why don't you just use ArcScan?

Comment: What is the reason for ArcScan ?

Comment: ArcScan does raster to vector conversion.

Comment: Ok. Didn't think that would work. I will give it a try.